# Parsing .json in Bash

Tags: json, jq

Have a `json` file I am trying to parse from `podfox` to allow me to rename the downloaded files in a "friendly" way.  Here's a snippet of `json` I am working with:

```
{
    "episodes": [
        {
             "title": "Hired and Fired by Little Richard and Jimi\u2019s first trip on LSD",
             "url": "https://www.podtrac.com/pts/redirect.mp3/chtbl.com/track/5899E/traffic.megaphone.fm/HSW2392375869.mp3",
             "downloaded": true,
             "listened": false,
             "published": 1582203660.0
        },
        {
             "title": "Stolen Cars, Broken Taboos, and the Search for Billy Davis",
             "url": "https://www.podtrac.com/pts/redirect.mp3/chtbl.com/track/5899E/traffic.megaphone.fm/HSW5134475908.mp3",
             "downloaded": true,
             "listened": false,
             "published": 1581598860.0
        },
    ]
    "shortname": "27 Club",
    "title": "27 Club",
    "url": "https://feeds.megaphone.fm/HSW5142951139"
}
```

I am trying to, based on the `url` get the `title` and pass that to a variable in `bash`.  I can (for the most part) use `grep` but I know that `jq` is a better method, I just cannot figure out the syntax to make `jq` work.

This works with grep on the command line: `grep -B 1 HSW2392375869.mp3 < feed.json | grep "title" | cut -d"\"" -f4` but seems like it is a potentially error prone solution.

When I try: `jq -c '.["episodes"].url'` the shell just hangs indefinitely. I do not require to use `jq` here, so any method to allow me to search for the `url` and return (ultimately) the value for `published` and `title` will do just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually first need to filter `.episodes` then the inner array

```
 jq ".episodes | .[0]" jsonfile
{
  "title": "Hired and Fired by Little Richard and Jimi’s first trip on LSD",
  "url": "https://www.podtrac.com/pts/redirect.mp3/chtbl.com/track/5899E/traffic.megaphone.fm/HSW2392375869.mp3",
  "downloaded": true,
  "listened": false,
  "published": 1582203660
}
```

title:

```
jq ".episodes| .[0].title" jsonfile
"Hired and Fired by Little Richard and Jimi’s first trip on LSD"
```

published:

```
jq ".episodes| .[0].published" jsonfile
1582203660
```

For query based on `url` value

```
jq '.episodes | .[] | select(.url=="https://www.podtrac.com/pts/redirect.mp3/chtbl.com/track/5899E/traffic.megaphone.fm/HSW2392375869.mp3").title' jsonfile    
"Hired and Fired by Little Richard and Jimi’s first trip on LSD"    

jq '.episodes | .[] | select(.url=="https://www.podtrac.com/pts/redirect.mp3/chtbl.com/track/5899E/traffic.megaphone.fm/HSW2392375869.mp3").published' jsonfile
1582203660
```

Comment: Or even `jq '.episodes | map(.title, (.url | sub(".*/"; ""))) '`

Comment: Aweseome! This is certainly a big step forward, but is there a way, with `jq` to find the url and then from that dataset get title and published?  The entire thing starts with matching a filename to a title.

Comment: @chow yes, I updated the answer.

Comment: @binarysta - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You want to query your JSON file using some URL and get the date of publication and title corresponding to that URL into shell variables.

```bsh
url='http://example.com/some/path'

title=unknown
published=unknown

eval "$(
    jq -r --arg url "$url" '.episodes[] | select(.url == $url) |
        @sh "title=\(.title); published=\(.published)"' file.json
)"

printf 'title     = "%s"\n' "$title"
printf 'published = "%s"\n' "$published"
```

This queries the objects in the `episodes` array for the one with the correct URL. If found, the `jq` expression will output shell code containing two variable assignments to the variables `title` and `published`.  The shell will evaluate these before outputting them with `printf`.

If no match is found, then the variables would not be changed.